# what does P stand for in change of coordinate and diagonalization?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

we use the notation $[\textbf{x}]_\mathcal{B}$ when we write the coordinates of a vector $\textbf{x}$ with respect to the basis $\mathcal{B}=\{\textbf{b}_1, \cdots, \textbf{b}_n \}$

and $\textbf{x}=P_\mathcal{B}[\textbf{x}]_\mathcal{B}$, where the columns of $P_\mathcal{B}$ are $\textbf{b}_1, \cdots, \textbf{b}_n$

and when we diagonalize a matrix, $A=PDP^{-1}$, where the columns of $P$ are the eigenvectors of $A$

what does P stand for in each case? I think they have something in common because we can choose a basis consisting of eigenvectors.

there are a lot of capital letters for matrices and most of them seem to make sense because they actually stand for something

for example, $S$ for symmetric, $D$ for diagonal, $Q$ for orthogonal (because $O$ can leads to misunderstanding for $0$), $A=LU$ where $L$ is for lower triangle and $U$ is for upper triangle, $A=QR$ where $R$ is for right triangle (=upper triangle)

but I have no idea about $P$ in $P_\mathcal{B}=\big[\textbf{b}_1 \cdots \textbf{b}_n\big]$ and $A=PDP^{-1}$

Comment: I wonder if it was chosen because it's near $Q$ for the special case when it's orthogonal, but I don't know why $Q$ is used for orthogonal matrices either. This might be good for [History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can understand matrices from the view of linear transformations. The similar matrices is essentially the same transformation in different bases.
So P represent a transition matrix between two bases!!

Comment: I believe that @chrononaute knows that but is looking for the word that starts with P.